# Как обычно хранят данные в приложениях?

Tags: c#, сериализация

Всем привет я новичок в c#. Мне нужно, чтобы программа сохраняла данные пользователя. Пользователь имеет возможность создавать колоды и хранить там созданные им карточки. Я думал сделать это с помощью сериализации, но не уверен в правильности подхода. Как я понял сериализацию используют для хранения настроек программы, но можно ли использовать такой подход пока не изучил БД?
В class Deck метод add делает сериализацию

```
namespace AnkiApp
{  
    public class Card
    {
        public enum Side { First, Second };

        public string FirstSide { get; set; }
        public string SecondSide { get; set; }
        public Side WhichSide { get; set; }

        public Card() { }
        public Card(string one, string two, Side side = Side.First)
        {
           FirstSide = one;
           SecondSide = two;
           WhichSide = side;
         }
    }

    class Deck
    {
        public static int counter = 0;
        public string NameDeck = "Default";
        public List<Card> Cards = new List<Card>();

        #region ctors

        public Deck()
        {
            NameDeck += counter.ToString();
            counter++;
        }


        public Deck(string name)
        {
            NameDeck = name;

        }
        #endregion

        public void add(Card cd)
        {
            //Add card in deck
            Cards.Add(cd);

            //Serialize deck
            XmlSerializer xmlFormat = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Card>));
            using (Stream fStream = new FileStream(NameDeck, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                xmlFormat.Serialize(fStream, Cards);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("=> Saved card in XML format!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Сериализация — это процесс преобразования объекта в поток байтов для сохранения или передачи в память, базу данных или файл. Эта операция предназначена для того, чтобы сохранить состояния объекта для последующего воссоздания при необходимости. Обратный процесс называется десериализацией. В итоге вам всё равно нужно будет указывать местоположения для хранения этих потоков, будь то база данных или файлы.

Comment: Самый простой способ - хранить информацию в json или xaml файлах. Просто преобразуете объект с строку и сохраняете в фай. Когда нужно получить информацию - считываете файл. В одном файле можно хранить хоть всю "бд" целиком. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: Все правильно делаете. Теперь реализуйте десериализацию, проверьте - работает? Наслаждайтесь!

Comment: разделите модель и логику сохранения данных. В этом случае вы легко сможете заменить последнюю, не трогая модель. При использовании JSON вы можете динамически выводить тип класса и вообще сделать универсальный сериализатор/десериализатор. Кроме того, насколько помню, на первых порах можно из можете сгенерировать с помощью VS и таблицу в базе данных (обычно наоборот, из таблицы делают модель).

Answer (score 2):

Как хранить данные в своей программе - исключительно ваше дело. Если вам нужно хранить несколько миллионов записей, то целесообразней использовать БД вроде Microsoft SQL Server или MySQL Server. Если у вас всего пара параметров, то можете сделать 1 файл Settings.xml и писать/читать оттуда эти значения.

В данном случае (база данных с адекватным количеством записей) целесообразно использовать хранение данных в .xml или .json файлах. Вы можете использовать сериализацию, если хотите сохранять колоды и карты именно как объекты - это быстрее в плане разработки. Также вы можете вручную записывать/читать данные, например, с помощью LINQ to XML. Если надумаете использовать JSON, то используйте не встроенный, а Newtonsoft.Json.